# Sending E-mails with a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: java, email, server

My school needs a server that sends emails automatically every day.
I know how to send an e-mail with Java.
So I thought it would be okay if I just use a `Raspberry Pi 2` for this little task.

My question is, whether or not it is possible to run a `Java` application on the *Raspberry Pi* that sends the `E-mail` every morning at *09:00 AM*? Is there another programming language that would suit better for this spefic task?

Comment: Yes, you can run Java on Pi. The latest Raspberry Pi release has java by default, otherwise there are tutorials to tell you how to install it. This is the wrong forum for this question though and you'll probably see some down votes for not providing an example of the steps you've taken.

Comment: I didn't take any steps yet so I can't provide examples ;) But thank you very much. I know how to install it but wasn't sure if Java is the right language for this.

Comment: Yeah, people are pretty unforgiving. I'm surprised it lasted this long.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what language you use. I'd use something much lighter-weight/less resource-intensive on the Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Java program that sends the e-mail already, then you can use a cron job to run the command on your Pi every morning at 9:00 AM.

Cron is a program that comes pre-installed on most UNIX-like operating systems, including Linux, and it simply runs a given command at intervals you specify.  Cron is always running in the background, so you don't need to call it directly, but you do need to edit a file to schedule your Java program to be run.

As root on your Raspberry pi, run the command `crontab -e` to open your crontab file for editing.  Then, add a line like this to the bottom, substituting the path I have given with the absolute path to your Java program.

```
0 9 * * * java -jar /path/to/your/program.jar
```

That will cause your Pi to run your Java program every single day at 9:00 AM, as long as the Pi is running.  This is a programming language-independent way of running commands at intervals, so the only thing your Java program must know how to do is send the correct e-mail whenever it is run.

Comment: Wow thank you very much :) But don't have have  to give CRON the jar file instead of the class file?

Comment: I am not a regular user of Java, so run whatever command you know will work. :-)  Good luck!

Comment: I have now edited my answer so that it runs a jar instead, for future visitors to the question.  Thanks for the tip, Marcel!